# Updating an xlsx file using OpenPyXL while file is open

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

I would just like to know if there is a way to update an existing xlsx file using **Openpyxl** while file is open.

I'm running a **RaspberryPi 3B+** as a stand alone computer and **LibreOffice** to open the xlsx file. I was already able to write to the file but whenever I have to run the script while the file is open, I always need to refresh/reload manually the file to be able to see the update.

Comment: No, this is not possible due to the way the files are structured.

Comment: Is there any other way/options that I can do update an xlsx file in real time using my set-up above?

Comment: No, as I said this is not possible.

Comment: @CharlieClark Any suggestions perhaps? My goal is just to update an xlsx file in real time while the file is open and what set-up can i do it with. (you can disregard my RPi set-up)

Comment: It is not technically possible to update an XLSX in real time.